# Is there a way to insert into elements of List2 alternately from elements of List1 quickly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Say there are two lists.

```
List1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
List2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

I want to print all possibilities with no repeats that meet the pattern below:

```
Res = [odd,even,odd,even,odd,even,odd,even,odd,even]
```

For example,

```
Res = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Res = [1,2,5,4,3,6,9,8,7,10]
Res = [3,2,1,4,9,6,5,10,7,8]
```

I tried to use itertools.product but I didn't know how to iterate by it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your requirements? Will the lists always consist of numbers? Or do you just want to alternate adding items between the two lists? Does odd even refer to the value of the item, or does it refer to which list the item comes from?

Comment: @elethan Always of course.I intent to pick up one element in List1, then pick up one element in List2, then pick up one of the residual elements in List1,then List2,...recursively.Finally I will get a list.The elements in the list are odd numbers and even numbers
that arrange alternately.I want to print all different permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> List1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> List2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(map(lambda x:list(itertools.chain(*zip(*x))), (itertools.product(itertools.permutations(List1), itertools.permutations(List2)))))
```

Comment: Thx for the answer.It's a way to insert into elements in one list from elements in another list alternately .But it's not the final result.

Comment: Nice! This way can solve such permutation questions.Thx.

Comment: You can also use the `itertools.chain` flattening idiom in that lambda (i.e, `lambda x: list(itertools.chain(*zip(*x)))` to shorten things a bit and use even more `itertools` fun.

Comment: @RandyC yes you are right, missed that, changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, somthing like:

```
np.ravel(np.column_stack((List1, List2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution in case the lists can contain a mix of odd and even values and the pattern criteria can vary:

```
import itertools as it

def combine_and_filter(lst1, lst2, criteria):
    perms = it.permutations(it.chain.from_iterable(zip(lst1, lst2)))
    return filter(lambda perm: all((v % 2 == c for v, c in zip(perm, criteria))), perms)

List1 = [1, 4, 7]
List2 = [2, 5, 8]

criteria1 = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ) # one for odd numbers, 0 for even
criteria2 = (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, )
criteria3 = (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, )

res1 = list(combine_and_filter(List1, List2, criteria1))
res2 = list(combine_and_filter(List1, List2, criteria2))
res3 = list(combine_and_filter(List1, List2, criteria3))

print(res1)
print(res2)
print(res3)
```

which produces:

> [(1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8), (1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 4), (1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 8), (1, 2, 7,
>   8, 5, 4), (1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8), (1, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2), (1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8),
>   (1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2), (1, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4), (1, 8, 5, 4, 7, 2), (1, 8, 7,
>   2, 5, 4), (1, 8, 7, 4, 5, 2), (5, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8), (5, 2, 1, 8, 7, 4),
>   (5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 8), (5, 2, 7, 8, 1, 4), (5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8), (5, 4, 1,
>   8, 7, 2), (5, 4, 7, 2, 1, 8), (5, 4, 7, 8, 1, 2), (5, 8, 1, 2, 7, 4),
>   (5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 2), (5, 8, 7, 2, 1, 4), (5, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2), (7, 2, 1,
>   4, 5, 8), (7, 2, 1, 8, 5, 4), (7, 2, 5, 4, 1, 8), (7, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4),
>   (7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 8), (7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2), (7, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8), (7, 4, 5,
>   8, 1, 2), (7, 8, 1, 2, 5, 4), (7, 8, 1, 4, 5, 2), (7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 4),
>   (7, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2)] [(1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 8), (1, 5, 2, 8, 7, 4), (1, 5, 4,
>   2, 7, 8), (1, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2), (1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4), (1, 5, 8, 4, 7, 2),
>   (1, 7, 2, 4, 5, 8), (1, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4), (1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 8), (1, 7, 4,
>   8, 5, 2), (1, 7, 8, 2, 5, 4), (1, 7, 8, 4, 5, 2), (5, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8),
>   (5, 1, 2, 8, 7, 4), (5, 1, 4, 2, 7, 8), (5, 1, 4, 8, 7, 2), (5, 1, 8,
>   2, 7, 4), (5, 1, 8, 4, 7, 2), (5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 8), (5, 7, 2, 8, 1, 4),
>   (5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 8), (5, 7, 4, 8, 1, 2), (5, 7, 8, 2, 1, 4), (5, 7, 8,
>   4, 1, 2), (7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8), (7, 1, 2, 8, 5, 4), (7, 1, 4, 2, 5, 8),
>   (7, 1, 4, 8, 5, 2), (7, 1, 8, 2, 5, 4), (7, 1, 8, 4, 5, 2), (7, 5, 2,
>   4, 1, 8), (7, 5, 2, 8, 1, 4), (7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 8), (7, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2),
>   (7, 5, 8, 2, 1, 4), (7, 5, 8, 4, 1, 2)] [(2, 1, 5, 4, 8, 7), (2, 1, 5,
>   8, 4, 7), (2, 1, 7, 4, 8, 5), (2, 1, 7, 8, 4, 5), (2, 5, 1, 4, 8, 7),
>   (2, 5, 1, 8, 4, 7), (2, 5, 7, 4, 8, 1), (2, 5, 7, 8, 4, 1), (2, 7, 1,
>   4, 8, 5), (2, 7, 1, 8, 4, 5), (2, 7, 5, 4, 8, 1), (2, 7, 5, 8, 4, 1),
>   (4, 1, 5, 2, 8, 7), (4, 1, 5, 8, 2, 7), (4, 1, 7, 2, 8, 5), (4, 1, 7,
>   8, 2, 5), (4, 5, 1, 2, 8, 7), (4, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7), (4, 5, 7, 2, 8, 1),
>   (4, 5, 7, 8, 2, 1), (4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 5), (4, 7, 1, 8, 2, 5), (4, 7, 5,
>   2, 8, 1), (4, 7, 5, 8, 2, 1), (8, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7), (8, 1, 5, 4, 2, 7),
>   (8, 1, 7, 2, 4, 5), (8, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5), (8, 5, 1, 2, 4, 7), (8, 5, 1,
>   4, 2, 7), (8, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1), (8, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1), (8, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5),
>   (8, 7, 1, 4, 2, 5), (8, 7, 5, 2, 4, 1), (8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1)]

note1: the lists were shortened for reducing the set of results

note2: I assume a tuple instead of a list would do for each permutation. If not, it's simple to create them replacing the return value with

```
return map(list, filter(lambda perm: all((v % 2 == c for v, c in zip(perm, criteria))), perms))
```